# Apply text box to edit the data field angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my grid view, there is a column name called `remark`. That field consists of many values including `absence`. I want to edit the `remark` value if it is only `absence` and after editing need to click the icon in front of that. Following mentioned the code I wrote.

```html
<div class="row"  *ngFor="let item_r of employee>
<div class="col-sm">
    <span *ngIf="item_r.remarks=='Absence'">
    <input    [value]=item_r.remarks (input)='item_r.remarks=$event.target.value'>
    <span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"        style="color:purple" title="Edit"   (click)="EditValue($event,item_r.remarks,item_r.log_id)" >
    </span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

When I started to editing the text box, it is disappeared due to condition is false. How should I make it as working properly.

[image]
Text box is only appeared when the remark='Absence'. When remark has different values like 'Travel'(Below attached the example), only that 'travel'
needs to display. no text boxes for remark values different from 'Absence'.

[image]

Comment: Give separate variable for text box and assign to the item_r.remarks object in the (blur) event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
 <div class="row"  *ngFor="let item_r of employee>
    <div class="col-sm" *ngInit="item_r.remarks=='Absence' as isAbs">
        <span *ngIf="isAbs">
        <input    [value]=item_r.remarks (input)='item_r.remarks=$event.target.value'>
        <span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"        style="color:purple" title="Edit"   (click)="EditValue($event,item_r.remarks,item_r.log_id)" >
        </span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATED**:

You can create custom directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[var]',
  exportAs: 'var'
})
class VarDirective {
  @Input() var:any;
}
```

**Template** :

```
<div class="row"  *ngFor="let item_r of employee">
    <div class="col-sm" #aVariable="var" var="item_r.remarks=='Absence'">
        <span *ngIf="aVariable.var">
        <input    [value]=item_r.remarks (input)='item_r.remarks=$event.target.value'>
        <span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"        style="color:purple" title="Edit"   (click)="EditValue($event,item_r.remarks,item_r.log_id)" >
        </span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have added my code to https://plnkr.co/edit/XfWbJ4OeZ33H9WNATRDe?p=preview

Comment: I tried using ngInit also. But it didn't work. The above solution displayed the empty records, not working.

Comment: Updated the answer. I have created a separate directive to initialize the variable in template also see the 
 code https://plnkr.co/edit/XfWbJ4OeZ33H9WNATRDe?p=preview

Comment: When using above code, text box is appeared for "null" remark values also.I want to avoid that. Purpose here is to text box is appeared only for remark='Absence'. If we have different remark values text box should not be appeared and need to display those remark values.